# How to avoid page reloading in my django front end?

Tags: javascript, html, django

every time I press submit button page gets reloaded.I have included preventdefault on submit.But it is not working.
Please help me.
This is part of html code .
Every time on submit I got redirected to another page.
I don't want page to reload. How  to fix this.

```
<form id='form' method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type='hidden' id='myusername' value='{{user}}'>
    <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary'>
</form>
```

```
{% block script %}
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reconnecting-websocket/1.0.0/reconnecting-websocket.js'></script>
<script>
var loc=window.location
var wsStart='ws://'
var formData=$("#form")
var me=$("#myusername").val()
var Holder=$("#items")
var msgInput=$("#id_message")
if(loc.protocol=='https:'){
    wsStart='wss://'
}
var endpoint=wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname+'/'
var socket=new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint)
socket.onmessage=function(e){
    console.log('message',e)
    var Data=JSON.parse(e.data)
    chatHolder.append('<li>'+Data.message+' via '+Data.username+'</li>')
}
socket.onopen=function(e){
    console.log('open',e)
    formData.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        var msgText=msgInput.val()
       var finalData={
           'message':msgText
       }
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(finalData))
        formData[0].reset()
    })
}
socket.onerror=function(e){
    console.log('error',e)
}
socket.onclose=function(e){
    console.log('close',e)
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: remove the action parameter from form tag

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

store the content from your form in a context dict then pass it to the new page maybe?

Comment: If I'm correct, you want to keep your input text as it is after submitting the form right?

Comment: No I dont want page to reload